# VirtualBox: Share VHD Disk between two guests

Tags: virtualbox, disk, vhd, vdi

We have two VBox guests, one Windows and one Ubuntu. Now we would like to use an additional (encrypted) data disk for both guests at the same time. We created an encrypted exFAT "shareable" VHD disk and added this disk to both guests. It works, the disk is writable from both guests. BUT: if guest A creates a new file or folder, guest B doesn't see it and vice versa. After unmount/mount or restarting the guest, everthing is visible. Why guest A cannot see changes from guest B in realtime? It's working with VDI instead of VHD?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution for your problem is to use this shared folder as an network share (nfs/smb share/sftp/ftp..) hosted on your host and connected to both guests as if they were just two computers on the same LAN

Comment: That's what we have done in the past. But shared folders have limitations compared to a disk, because guest operating systems behave different if they recognize a network device instead of a disk. That's why we are looking for a different solution.

Comment: I don't think you'll find any other solution other then some kind of network drive, because practically what you are asking to do is connect a hard drive to two computers at the same time.. every solution I know related to shared storage uses some kind of protocol in order to manage everything and prevent two machines writing at the same time on the same blocks.. But I hope I am wrong and you will find a proper solution! I'm still following this question :)

Comment: thanks for your input .. it seems we go on with shared folders :(

Comment: Yep.. thinking more about your issue I remembered that even hosts in a vCenter cluster which usually share storage use some kind of network based shared storage.